# wait for the next alert signal if the conditions are currently met

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

i'm making an alarm to tell me when a red bar's high is being broken.
if i set the alarm when the last red bar is not broken yet, the alarm will work just fine ..

but the problem is :
if i set the alarm when the last red is already broken, the alarm will trigger immediately.

is there a way to code the alarm to wait for the next red to be broken, if we are already above the last red bar high?

thanks.

here is the code

```
redCandle = barstate.isconfirmed and open>close
redcandlehigh= ta.valuewhen(redCandle,high,0)
GreenBarBroke= open < close and close>redcandlehigh
alertcondition(GreenBarBroke, title='Green', message='Green broke')
```

Comment: @vitruvius

that's actually clever ,thank you very much. the way i tried it was to check last high to make sure it didn't break the last red. then i would know that the current bar's high is the first to break.

"high>=redcandlehigh and high[1]<=redcandlehigh"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the price opened below the red bar high, so you would know that the price broke the high level on that bar.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var float last_red_high = na
is_green = close >= open
is_red = not is_green
last_red_high := is_red ? high : last_red_high
is_red_high_broken = (open < last_red_high) and (close > last_red_high)

plot(last_red_high, "Last Red High", color.yellow, 2, plot.style_circles)
plotshape(is_red_high_broken, "Red High Broken", shape.xcross, location.abovebar, color.white)
alertcondition(is_red_high_broken, "Red High Broken")
```

White "x"s are where your alerts would be triggered.

[image]